# Gradient Descent Classification with 5 labels and 9 features

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, gradient-descent

I have a set of data, each entry has 9 "features" (positive numbers ranging from 1e-3 to 9e3), and I need to use each entry's features to select one of 5 possible labels for the entry.

I know I need to define a scoring function that takes in features, weights them, and returns a number reflecting how likely each label is given those features and weights. The loss function will be convex over the inputs: it will return the difference between the output of the scoring function and the human-provided labels. The weight matrix of the scoring function will be optimized with gradient descent such that the loss is minimized.

Specifically, I have something that looks like this:

```
entry 1> (ground-truth label), [0.9, 0.2, 1e-2, 6.853, 0.882 ... 1]
    *prediction: label 3* *actually: label 4* *loss = some number, update weights*
entry 2> (ground-truth label), [features 1...9]
    *prediction: label 1* *actually: label 1* *loss = 0, don't update weights*
...
entry 80,000> (etc...)
```

How do I choose a scoring function that maps these features to a likelihood of one of the five possible labels?

Would it look like:

```
for (loop through all data)
    [features] <dot product> [weights] = prediction
    if(prediction near (number))
        assign label 1
    else if (prediction near (number 2)
        assign label 2
    else (etc...)

    hinge_loss_function(prediction) = loss
    [weights] = loss*stepsize
end for
```

This feels very wrong but I am new to gradient descent. Any ideas on how to do multi-label classification?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear! Why?

**First**, if you have training data with two labels, then how can you design a model for five class classification problem? During training your model doesn't know what are the other three classes, so during testing how can it predict that an instance belong to those unknown three classes?

You can think of some unsupervised classification techniques, like clustering where you don't need to have true labels for the training instances. But I am not sure what your requirements are!

**Second**, gradient descent (an optimization algorithm) is not a classification problem solving technique rather it can be used to solve minimization problems. Say, you have designed a model where you have an objective function (including model parameters). You can use gradient descent to minimize that objective function to find out the best model parameters.

I encourage you to read the wiki article on [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). If you have training data with true labels, you can use say, any supervised classification model, ex., logistic regression or SVM etc with gradient descent technique to find out the model parameters.

---

**Update**

Your provided algorithm is close but requires some modification. Simply we can summarize the gradient descent learning as follows:

[image]

---

We can translate the above algorithm into a more mathematical notation as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at my question - I've edited it to provide more detail and hopefully better reflect what I understand about gradient descent.
Note that there are five possible labels, and each line of the data has been assigned ground-truth human labels.

Comment: I have updated my answer. if that helps you, you can upvote and/or accept it.